# Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all subsets $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ so that $A$ or $A^c$ are countable. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all subsets $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ so that $A$ or $A^c$ are countable. Show that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field.

Following Durrett's definition in his textbook, its enough to show that (i) if $A\in \mathcal{F}$ than $A^c\in \mathcal{F}$ and (ii) if $A_i\in \mathcal{F}$ is a countable sequence of sets than $\bigcup_i A_i \in \mathcal{F}$.

Showing the first is trivial, and basically follows from the definition. I'm having a hard time showing (ii) though, any help?

Answer (score 3):

Consider two cases, depending on whether there is an index $i$ for which the set $A_i$ is not countable. If the index does not exist, then remember a countable union of countable sets is countable. If the index does exist, then what can you say about the size of $(\bigcap_j A_j)^c$ relative to $A_i^c$?